# Storing file input into structures in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, input, struct

I'm able to import the file and read it, but I don't think it's saving to the structure. I want to figure out how to save it within the structure so I can search/ delete the contacts. The unfortunately lengthy code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 500
//Structure for contacts. These are now pointers.
typedef struct friends_contact{

  char *First_Name;
  char *Last_Name;
  char *home;
  char *cell;
}fr;
//Function declarations 
void menu(fr*friends ,int* counter,int i,char buffer[]);
void setFirst(fr*,int *,int i,char buffer[]);
char getFirst(fr*,int i);
void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]);
char getLast(fr*friends , int i);
void setHome(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]);
char getHome(fr*friends, int i);
void setCell(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]);
char getCell(fr*friends, int i);
void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i,char buffer[]);
void print_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]);
char delete_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i);
int show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i);
void file(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]);
void file2 (fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char buffer[],FILE*read);

int main() 
{
  fr friends[5];
  char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
  int counter=0;
  int i=0;

  menu(friends, &counter,i,buffer);

  getch();
  return 0;
}
//Menu function
void menu(fr*friends,int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{
 int user_entry=0;
 int user_entry1=0;
 int user_entry2=0;
 char user_entry3[50]={'\0'};
 FILE *read;
 printf("Welcome! Would you like to import a file? (1)Yes or (2) No");
 scanf("%d",&user_entry1);
 if(user_entry1==1)
   {
    printf("Please enter a file name");
    scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
    read=fopen(user_entry3,"r");
   }else;

 do{
  int result;

  printf("\nPhone Book Application\n");
  printf("1) Add friend\n2) Delete friend\n3) Show a friend\n4) Show  phonebook\n5)Exit\n");   
  scanf("%d", &user_entry);
if(user_entry==1)
  {
    add_contact(friends,counter,i,buffer);
  }
if(user_entry==2)
  {
    delete_contact(friends ,counter,i);
  } 
if(user_entry==3)
  {
    result=show_contact(friends ,counter,i);
    if(result==0){
                  printf("\nName not Found\n");
                  }else{
                        result;
                        }

 }                  
if(user_entry==4)
 {
   print_contact(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
   if(user_entry1==1)
     {
   file2(friends ,counter,i,buffer,read);
      }else;
 } 

}while(user_entry!=5);
  if(user_entry==5)
    {
      printf("Would you like to save entries to a file? (1)yes or (2) no");
      scanf("%d",&user_entry2);
      if(user_entry2 == 1)
        {
          printf("Please name your file");
          scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
          file(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
          printf("Goodbye!"); 

     }else if(user_entry2 == 2)
        {
     printf("Goodbye!"); 
        }

    }

 }
//Start of Set functions. Each entry has its own set function that gathers the data
//For each interaction, we have a buffer and a malloc.
void setFirst(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{
  printf("Enter a first name \n");
  scanf("%s",buffer);

  friends[*counter].First_Name=malloc(BUFFSIZE*strlen(buffer));
  strcpy(friends[*counter].First_Name, buffer);

}

void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{

  printf("Enter a last name \n");
  scanf("%s",buffer);

  friends[*counter].Last_Name=malloc(BUFFSIZE*strlen(buffer));
  strcpy(friends[*counter].Last_Name, buffer);
}
void setHome(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{

  printf("Enter a home number \n");
  scanf("%s",buffer);

  friends[*counter].home=malloc(BUFFSIZE*strlen(buffer));
  strcpy(friends[*counter].home, buffer);
}
void setCell(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{

  printf("Enter a cell number \n");
  scanf("%s",buffer);

  friends[*counter].cell=malloc(BUFFSIZE*strlen(buffer));
  strcpy(friends[*counter].cell, buffer);
}
//Start of Get functions. Each function sends the data to the executing function.
char getFirst(fr*friends , int pos) 
{

   printf("%s ", friends[pos].First_Name);
   return *friends[pos].First_Name;
}

char getLast(fr*friends , int pos)
{

   printf("%s\n", friends[pos].Last_Name);
   return *friends[pos].Last_Name;

}

char getHome(fr*friends , int pos) 
{

   printf("(Home) ""%s\n", friends[pos].home);
   return *friends[pos].home;
}

char getCell(fr*friends , int pos) 
{

   printf("(Cell) ""%s\n", friends[pos].cell);
   return *friends[pos].cell;
}
//This function allows for the all the set functions to be added.
void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i,char buffer[]) 
{
   setFirst(friends,counter,i,buffer); 
   setLast(friends,counter,i,buffer);
   setHome(friends,counter,i,buffer);
   setCell(friends,counter,i,buffer);
   (*counter)++;
}

//This is used to delete a name out of the book.
char delete_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i)
{
   char name_search[50]={'\0'};
   char Delete[5]={'\0'};

   printf("Search by last name\n");
   scanf("%s",name_search);//Name entry
   for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
      {
       if(strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)//Copys over the name entered
         {                                       
          strcpy(friends[i].Last_Name,Delete);
         }
       }
    //Freeing up memory.
    free(friends[i].First_Name);
    free(friends[i].Last_Name);
    free(friends[i].home);
    free(friends[i].cell);   

    printf("\nName(s) has been deleted\n");             
}
//This function prints out all the contact information
void print_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]) 
{
    for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
    if (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name)&&        strlen(friends[i].home)&& strlen(friends[i].cell ))
       {

          getFirst(friends, i);
          getLast(friends, i);
          getHome(friends, i);
          getCell(friends, i);
        }
}
//Displays the contact in which you are searching for.
int show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i) 
{  
   char name_search2[50]={'\0'};
   int flag=0;
   printf("Please enter a last name\n");
   scanf("%s",name_search2);
   for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
      {
      //If the name is found, it reaturns the contact info.Now works for duplicate last names.
        if(strcmp(name_search2,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)
          {
             (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name)&& strlen(friends[i].home)&& strlen(friends[i].cell ));

            getFirst(friends, i);
            getLast(friends, i);
            getHome(friends, i);
            getCell(friends, i);
            flag++;
          }
     }         


    return flag;
}    
void file(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[5])
{
FILE*fp;
char flag2;
fp=fopen(user_entry3,"w");

for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
   {
     if (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name)&&    strlen(friends[i].home)&& strlen(friends[i].cell ))
        {

        fprintf(fp,"\n""%s ",friends[i].First_Name);
        fprintf(fp,"%s ""\n",friends[i].Last_Name);
        fprintf(fp,"<Home>""%s""\n",friends[i].home);
        fprintf(fp,"<Cell>""%s""\n",friends[i].cell);

        }
  }
   fclose(fp);
}

void file2(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char buffer[],FILE*read)
{
  fseek(read, 0, SEEK_SET); 

  while (fscanf(read,"%s", buffer) != EOF) 
     {
       friends[*counter].Last_Name=malloc(BUFFSIZE*strlen(buffer));

       strcpy(friends[*counter].Last_Name, buffer);

       printf("%s\n",friends[*counter].Last_Name);

      }

}
```

I understand the code isn't perfect, and might have a few flaws that aren't related to this question, but I've been trying for a while to figure this issue out. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out !

Comment: couldn't understand what you need?

Comment: As of right now the program will read a file that is entered by the user. Lets say the text file contains a name and 2 numbers, it prints it in the contacts list, but I can't delete the name or search the name once the file is read into the contacts list. Im assuming this is because the program is simply reading the file, but not saving the file. I'm looking to try and save whats into the file, into the structure, so I can delete/search the names provided from the file.

Comment: Does the data outputs to screen correctly once read from file? Are changes made to data before user saves the file?

Comment: yes, data output is displayed as it should be. for example I will have a persons name and 2 numbers in a file, when I call that file at the start of the program, I can look in the `show phonebook` and the name and number will be there. If I choose the search function though, and type the name, it says name not found. If I choose the delete option, the name is never deleted from the phonebook.

Comment: `menu()`->`if(user_entry==3)`->`else` result is just a variable,what will it do?

Comment: `result=show_contact(friends ,counter,i);` Now that you've pointed that out I see that `result` is pretty useless, but nevertheless, `result` is used to call the show_contact function. I think this was something I was playing around with when I first created this program, and just forgot to change it back. Regardless, I don't think this is where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the file into the friends structure in the function file2, but you call file2 only when the entered option is 4 - in the following code segment.

```
if(user_entry==4)
 {
   print_contact(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
   if(user_entry1==1)
     {
   file2(friends ,counter,i,buffer,read);
      }else;
 }
```

In case of search or delete (user_entry =2 or user_entry=3) the file is never read into the structure and hence the issue.
You need to ensure that you call file2 for these cases as well.

Comment: but wont that simply just print out the list rather then actually modify it? I get what you are saying, but simply just calling the `file2` function should just print what's in the file. Or maybe I'm completely wrong, I am the one asking for help after all lol.

Comment: If you want to search thru the friends structure you need to populate it first. Now you are populating the structure in file2, so obviously you need to call that first before you read. You can always modify the logic to not print in file2. Rather move the printing logic into another function which only prints the content in the structure. So file2 will only populate the structure from the file.

Comment: I guess where I am getting confused is where to call it. For example my delete function simply searches for a last name within the structure not within another function. So if file2 is saving the data to the structure, shouldn't it work as though I added the data from within the program?

Comment: call file2 before the do while loop. That way the structure is populated before you search or delete

Comment: still same results, this is maddening! I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You may open the file in`r+` mode. And if your code needs a sync between data in memory and data in disc you can achieve so by opening the file in this mode and update the file as you need e.g. when a entry is completed by the user.

Comment: i tried `read=fopen(user_entry3,"r+");` and it had the same results.